# How to download website content with fully-styling using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am going to build chrome extension that downloads the website with fully-styling like SingleFile chrome extension.
As most of the website is based on HTTPS, I couldn't use XMLHTTPRequest.
Are there any way that can handle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just right-click and "Save as..." an HTML page?

Comment: Please use [chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageCapture/#method-saveAsMHTML) .